# 0x8001010A (RPC_E_SERVERCALL_RETRYLATER)) exception occurs when creating object of Excel in c#

Tags: c#, .net, excel, com-interop

I am working on an excutable written in C#, which basically opens an existing Excel file (in C# using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel dll) and do some manipulation over it. 
Code works fine for my user account, but when I **run the same code under a different user(admin role)** then it throws an exception at the line of `_excel = new Application();`

```
_excel = new Application(); // throws an exception
_excel.Visible = _showExcel;
```

Following is the exception details -

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} from the IClassFactory failed due to the following error: 8001010a The message filter indicated that the application is busy. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010A (RPC_E_SERVERCALL_RETRYLATER)).
at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
```

In task manager, i can see Excel process after this exception occured.

Using <kbd>Computer Management</kbd>><kbd>System Tools</kbd>><kbd>Local Users and Groups</kbd>><kbd>Groups</kbd>><kbd>Administrators</kbd> , I confirmed that user is in admin role.

I am running Exe file using powershell command prompt (openning as a different user)

I already googled a lot of pages related to this error, but I did not get any success related to my specific issue.

Comment: can anyone provide their valuable comments

Answer (score 1):

this exception is thrown because Excel is busy and will not service any Object Model calls.
try following code:

```
 xlWorkSheet.EnableSelection = xlWorkSheet.EnableSelection = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlEnableSelection.xlNoSelection;
```

and if will not work follow [microsoft solution](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228772.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for replying, but i dont think so its gonna work as this issue is coming only on one Environment i.e. SandBox. On UAT ,SVT, POC environment same code works fine with the same user account